# Setting up mediawiki on ubuntu machine. How do I upload images?

Tags: mediawiki

I just installed mediawiki on my ubuntu machine, and was wondering how I can upload images in to an article I'm writing.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the normal file upload function of MediaWiki as described in http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Managing_files